# How do I temporarily update an extension configuration value in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a `suse-vale-styleguide` VSCode extension. It is a simple extension to an existing `vale-vscode` extension which uses a `valeCLI.config` config option to specify a path to its config file.
My `suse-vale-styleguide` brings its own configuration file `.vale.ini` and needs to temporarily modify the `valeCLI.config` option. That part is quite easy and works fine.

The problem is that the temporary `.vale.ini` is placed inside the `suse-vale-styleguide` directory which is for example `~/.vscode-oss/extensions/opensuse.suse-vale-styleguide-0.2.3-universal/` and it changes with each extension update. The `vale-vscode` extension after `suse-vale-styleguide` update searches its `.vale.ini` in a wrong place reporting en error. Is there a way to solve it? For example a storage for extensions that does not yield its version numbers? or a completely better way of doing things? For completeness, here is my code (the deactivation does not work):

```js
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
const vscode = require('vscode');
const fs = require('fs');
var oldValeIniPath = '';
// get config obj for vale plugin
var valeConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('vale');


// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {
    // get the current .vale.ini path
    let oldValeIniPath = valeConfig.get('valeCLI.config');
    //vscode.window.showInformationMessage(currentValeIniPath);
    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Old .vale.ini path: ' + oldValeIniPath);
    // check if the current path exists (may not after extension upgrade) and
    // save it if yes
    if (fs.existsSync(oldValeIniPath)) {
        console.log('The path is valid');
    } else {
        console.error('The path is invalid');
        oldValeIniPath = '';
    }
    // construct the .vale.ini path for this extension and set it
    let curValeConfigPath = context.extensionPath + '/.vale.ini';
    valeConfig.update('valeCLI.config', curValeConfigPath);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {
    valeConfig.update('valeCLI.config', oldValeIniPath)
}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

Comment: the `context` argument of `activate` has the directory of the extension

Comment: sure, but it changes with each version update of the extension, and i seem to have no means to inform the original extension about the changed path to its INI file

Comment: if you restore the orig path each time, what is the problem that you use the new extension path at the next activation

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the extension's gobalStorage:

```js
let globalStorageURI = context.globalStorageUri;
if (fs.existsSync(globalStorageURI.path) == false) {
    fs.mkdir(globalStorageURI.path);
}
let globalValeConfigPath = globalStorageURI.path + '/.vale.ini';
```

and wrote the `.vale.ini` config there from the code:

```js
let valeIni = 'StylesPath = ...';
//write the content of .vale.ini into the global strage file
fs.writeFileSync(globalValeConfigPath, valeIni);
valeConfig.update('valeCLI.config', globalValeConfigPath);
```